# Laravel convert json to array adds "r" character

Tags: jquery, json, response, laravel-5

Laravel return [json](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#json-responses) response like :

`"r{"name":["alex"]}"`

as you see there is a `r` in response which prevent `$.parseJSON` to render it .
how may i convert this response to an array? and why laravel return that `r`?

Comment: May we see how you are generating this response? It should not contain an `r`, nothing about the [method](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_json) would add it.

Comment: please take a look [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13855) , i think this is a  laravel bug

Comment: Interesting. Is the issue still present if you do something like `response()->json(['status' => 1]);`? I'm thinking something in `$validator->errors()->toArray()` is causing the issue. Also, are you using any custom error messages for your validation?

Comment: @camelCase thanks. issue solved. *`are you using any custom error messages for your validation`* point me out to validation translate file. and there were a redundant `r` at the very first line of `lang/en/validation.php`